# Oracle Database: Find Missing Indexes for Performance tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, plsql, oracle11g

We are currently doing database performance tuning. Does Oracle database have any DMV Select Queries to find missing indexes directly?

Microsoft SqlServer has this below:  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/03/sql-server-2008-missing-index-script-download/

```
-- Missing Index Script
-- Original Author: Pinal Dave 
SELECT TOP 25
dm_mid.database_id AS DatabaseID,
dm_migs.avg_user_impact*(dm_migs.user_seeks+dm_migs.user_scans) Avg_Estimated_Impact,
dm_migs.last_user_seek AS Last_User_Seek,
OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) AS [TableName],
'CREATE INDEX [IX_' + OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) + '_'
+ REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(dm_mid.equality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','') 
+ CASE
WHEN dm_mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL
AND dm_mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN '_'
ELSE ''
END
+ REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(dm_mid.inequality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','')
+ ']'
+ ' ON ' + dm_mid.statement
+ ' (' + ISNULL (dm_mid.equality_columns,'')
+ CASE WHEN dm_mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND dm_mid.inequality_columns 
IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE
'' END
+ ISNULL (dm_mid.inequality_columns, '')
+ ')'
+ ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + dm_mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS Create_Statement
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups dm_mig
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats dm_migs
ON dm_migs.group_handle = dm_mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details dm_mid
ON dm_mig.index_handle = dm_mid.index_handle
WHERE dm_mid.database_ID = DB_ID()
ORDER BY Avg_Estimated_Impact DESC
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one good resource: https://www.dba-scripts.com/scripts/diagnostic-and-tuning/troubleshooting/find-missing-index/

If anyone has more answers, feel free to post

```
ACCEPT SCHEMA_NAME PROMPT 'Choose the schema to analyze:'

select * from (
  select 'the column ' || c.name || ' of the table ' || us.name || '.' || o.name || ' was used ' || u.equality_preds || ' times in an equality predicate and ' || u.equijoin_preds || ' times in an equijoin predicate and is not indexed' as colum_to_index
  from sys.col_usage$ u,
       sys.obj$ o,
       sys.col$ c,
       sys.user$ us
  where u.obj# = o.obj#
  and   u.obj# = c.obj#
  and   us.user# = o.owner#
  and   u.intcol# = c.col#
  and   us.name='&SCHEMA_NAME'
  and   c.name not in (select column_name from dba_ind_columns where index_owner ='&SCHEMA_NAME')
  and   (u.equality_preds > 100 OR u.equijoin_preds > 100)
  order by u.equality_preds+u.equijoin_preds desc)
WHERE rownum <11;
```